# Unique identifier for Exchange emails?

Tags: .net, email, unique, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

Here is my setting:

- Exchange server 2007
- Using EWS Managed API 2.0
- .Net application

**What I am trying to do:** I need to keep track of all emails related to some task in the system, some are sent from the system and others recieved from outside.

**Problem:** as of now, I couldnt find a way to **uniquely** identify the emails! Researching this issue I found out that I cant use *ItemID.UniqueID* because it might change overtime, I also cant use *StoreEntryId* because its for *Exchange Server 2010 and later*, and finally I cant add a new *extended property* since not all emails are sent from the system!

**Any idea on how can I do that?**

Comment: How being the emails are coming from different system is a problem for adding extended property ?

Comment: I add the extended properties to the email before I send it, and I am not sure that I can add the extended properties once the email is received.

Comment: of you are using the streaming notification, once you recieve an email, there will be a notification received, this notification contains the item itself and in this case it is the mail, so you should put the extended property once you handle the notification .